# javafx runtime thread synchronization error?

Tags: multithreading, exception, runtime, javafx-2

I was wondering if anyone could elaborate on the following errors without having to post my entire code. I have an object that draws an image and a threaded object that draws another image on top. Whenever the image visible area is changed by click and dragging the mouse I sometimes get this error and my application freezes.

```
java.lang.InternalError: Unrecognized PGCanvas token: 68
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderStream(NGCanvas.java:699)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:339)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:181)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.InternalError: Unrecognized PGCanvas token: 68
```

Comment: My first thought is JavaFX GUI manipulations must be done in JavaFX main thread. Are you using Platform.runLater();?

Comment: No and how do you use Platform.runLater(); Also I am using java.lang.Thread.

Comment: The runLater() method takes a Runnable as a parameter. Try searching the net and SO, you will find usages and description of it. If you want I will post a sample code later.

Comment: I got a different error this time.  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -11
 at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Vector.get(Unknown Source)
 at Chart.draw(Chart.java:169)
 at Chart.vectorPoint(Chart.java:125)
 at Chart.access$300(Chart.java:28)
 at Chart$4.handle(Chart.java:88)
 at Chart$4.handle(Chart.java:85)

Comment: Fixed the vector issue.  Code you post a code example. Thanks

Comment: I tried Platform.runLater() but that just made things hang.  I removed it and ran my app and so far I can't regenerate the same error or any error at all. I guess I solved my own problem. Lol

Comment: Ok then glad to hear that.